# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'component' is not a known element:

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am facing the problem in angular 4.4 , In my app, I have hierarchical view. In which I have created a

**:= module 1 -> module 2 -> my component.**

I have declared everything correctly. , But still I'm getting error.

1. **Declared** component.
2. **Imported** it into other module.
3. **selector** name is same.
4. **Exported** component in **module 2**.
5. **Imported** module 2 in **module 1**.

**What could be the catch?**
Component Code:
Admin -> Configuration -> mycomponent
//My component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'test-mycomponent',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('myComponentTable')

  constructor() {
    }
  ngOnInit() {
//init functionality
}
}

// configure module code 
import { NgModule,Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MyComponentComponent } from './mycomponent/mycomponent.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    WidgetsModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  exports: [
    MyComponent
  ]
})
export class ConfigurationModule { }

//Main module admin
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ConfigurationModule } from './configuration/configuration.module';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MyComponentComponent } from './configuration/mycomponent/mycomponent.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule,
    ConfigurationModule
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  exports: [
     ]
})
export class AdminModule { }

and I am calling that template in another file
//Test file html 
    <ng-template>
          <test-mycomponent></test-mycomponent>
      </ng-template>
```

Comment: can you please add code ..

Comment: @AmolRaje Plz check

Answer (score 1):

You are not declaring the right component the name should be MyComponentComponent in the declerations and exports:

```
import { MyComponentComponent } from './mycomponent/mycomponent.component';

declarations: [
    MyComponent //should be MyComponentComponent 
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  exports: [
    MyComponent //should be MyComponentComponent 
  ]
```

Comment: I have corrected that in my code, but still the same error.